# Creating a DataFrame with 4 Vectors, Then labeling then grouping the values by vector source

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I am trying to create a df with four vectors, each with 10,000 observations. I need all 40,000 observations to basically be in one vector within the df and then I need a second vector that groups them based on the set they came from (vector 1, vector 2, vector 3, or vector 4). Help!

Here is an attempt at showing an example:

```
x1 <- c(1,2,3,...10,000)
x2 <- c(1,2,3,...10,000)
x3 <- c(1,2,3,...10,000)
x4 <- c(1,2,3,...10,000)
```

Basically, I need to, I think, combine these into one df, but I want to retain a reference to which vector the values come from. So, imagine one vector within the df that stores all 40,000 observations and a second vector that categorizes them by 1,2,3,4, according to the source vector of the observation.
I need to do this, I think, because I want a facet_graph plot.

I know I'm not good at asking this question, but I read the FAQs/Docs, and I'm really trying.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have your data in long format, make a new data frame for each vector and have a column with data on the vector, then bind the rows together.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

v1 <- c(1:15)
v2 <- c(16:30)
v3 <- c(31:45)
v4 <- c(46:60)

df <- bind_rows(
  data_frame(vec = 1, val = v1),
  data_frame(vec = 2, val = v2),
  data_frame(vec = 3, val = v3),
  data_frame(vec = 4, val = v4)
)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = val)) +
  geom_area(stat = "bin", bins = 10) +
  facet_grid(. ~ vec)
```